# How to include header files with similar names in C++ project

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am using an external library in my C++ program. This library has a fie named "Common.h". Without knowing about this file, I also created a "Common.h" in my program. Using the compiler flag "#pragma once" in the headers I could ensure that both the  files can be included in the compilation. However, I realized that when I call my "Common.h" in my program, the preprocessor wrongly includes the "Common.h" from the external  library which breaks the compilation. Is there any option like "namespace" which allows me to include the correct file. I find it really difficult, as we may not (indeed need not) aware about all the files in the external library.

Comment: The only way to differentiate them while using the same name is by include some or all of the file path in the include directive.

Comment: You can store your headers in a project sub-folder and `#include "my_project/Common.h"`. TBH The library should already do that for itself. Maybe you have the compiler's include flags set incorrectly?

Comment: Let the folder name be the namespace of the header file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually program has several so called *include paths* to look for header files. It seems you have included both path to directory containing your *"Common.h"* file, as well as library headers directory. As for me, perfect solution seems to remove include path of library files and use explicit relative path, as:

```
#include "mylib/include/Common.h"
```

Comment: one shouldn't forget that there is #include <> and #include "" which have different priorities. One with <> looks among platform-defined folders (implementation-specific), other - in project's folder at first, non-recursively so partial paths should be used (there are implementation specifics, but that's mostly because of the vast  amount of different platforms)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename your "common.h" file and then include that

Comment: Please see my reply to yugr